# Why doesn't the user link appear?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

From [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/192544):

[image]

The above question was closed as a duplicate by 5 users. However, a link doesn't appear for the user "Mik".

Is his account deleted?
If yes then, Ask Ubuntu can delete any user if he was done anything wrong.

Comment: Mik had posted some great answers.

Comment: Sadly, Mik is now just a number: user76204. I don't know why :(

Comment: Probably got deleted (as vasa1 says). It's not often a 3k+ user gets deleted..

Comment: Mik's account was active as recently as 20140101. Now, I have to edit [my answer here](http://askubuntu.com/a/398488/25656).

Comment: Sadly, vasa1 is now just a number:user25656.I don't know why :(

Answer (score 3):

I think the comments have covered it.

- The user was deleted at their own request.
- Deletion denormalises the user record and leaves their name.
- There's nothing to link to so the system doesn't.

Comment: do you know why the user requested to delete his account?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Nope. They dealt with somebody at SE directly.

Comment: That's a real pity, because Mik was such a good user..

Comment: I hope he/she reads this!

Comment: @Oli why vasa1's account got deleted?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Because they requested it.

Comment: why people are asking to delete his accounts.I don't know what the reason behind this.

Comment: @AvinashRaj As I said (and the same rings true for vasa1) these people are dealing with SE directly.